# Reading missing values from UserDefaults

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, swift3, userdefaults

I want to store font size in user defaults and read it in next runs.
But in first run when I check font size using code below, it returns 0, while I expect an exception or something like that which says this value is not saved before:

```
let font_size=CGFloat(UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "fontsize"))
```

Now `font_size` is 0 which should be nil or throw an exception!

The Apple document says :
**The floating-point value associated with the specified key. If the key does not exist, this method returns 0.**

But I don't like **0** But I want to know if this value is stored before or not!

Answer (score 3):

`NSUserDefaults` uses `NSNumber` to keep numeric values, so you can write something like this:

```
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "fontsize") != nil {
        let fontSize = CGFloat(UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "fontsize"))
        //use `fontSize`...
    } else {
        //first run...
    }
```

Or:

```
    if let fontSize = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "fontsize") as? CGFloat {
        //use `fontSize`...
    } else {
        //first run...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> I expect an exception or something like that which says this value is
>   not saved before

Exceptions are not supported in Swift

> But I don't like 0

Use [registerDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/registerDefaults:) to provide your own base value.

> But I want to know if this value is stored before or not!

I assume you don't allow the user to set font size 0, so if the value is 0 it means it hasn't been set yet.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I don't think 0 makes sense to be the value of a variable called `fontSize`. How can you have text which is size 0? So this isn't really a problem at all.

Just limit the user to select a font size that's above 0. This way, if you get a 0 from the user defaults, you will know that the value has not been set yet.

What if the valid range includes 0?

This is a brute force solution, but it works anyway.

When you save the value, always add one to it. When you get the value back, subtract one. Again, if you get 0, you know the value has not been set.

Comment: I guess you misread the question. It said "in first run ... returns 0". That means that the user didn't take any action yet but the return default was 0 for an unset value (see post by OOPer).

Comment: @Michael I didn't. My point is that `0` is not a valid font size anyway, so the answer to the question "I want to know if this value is stored before or not!" is "check whether it is 0".

Comment: This might be an appropriate answer for this specific question but if the variable would represent something else then `0` might be a valid entry and your approach would fail.

Answer (score 1):

You could register defaults when checking for the first run of the app.

```
func checkFirstRun() {
    let currentVersion = (Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as! String) + " (" + (Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleVersion"] as! String) + ")"
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let value = defaults.dictionaryRepresentation()["KEY_FOR_INSTALLED_VERSION"]
    if(value == nil) {
        // first run after installation
        var appDefaults = Dictionary<String, Any>()
        appDefaults["fontsize"] = YOUR_DEFULT_FONT_SIZE            
        defaults.register(defaults: appDefaults)
    } else if(currentVersion != (defaults.object(forKey: "KEY_FOR_INSTALLED_VERSION") as! String)) {
        // app update            
    }
    defaults.set(currentVersion, forKey: "KEY_FOR_INSTALLED_VERSION")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation for UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html) tells you: You can (and for your purpose probably should) set default values for the values. You have to add

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
let appDefaults: [String:Any] = ["fontSize" : 10,
                                 "anotherUserDefaultValue" : "Not found",
                                 "firstLaunch" : true]
userDefaults.register(defaults: appDefaults)
```

to your AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.